# LinearLayout in Android API Level 10 (2.3), background affects whole element

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following element

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/black_border">
```

And black_border is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#000"/>

</shape>
```

The desired result is a 1px black border around the elements inside the LinearLayout.

On my device (running 5.0/Level 21) everything looks good, the contents of that element are grouped by a 1px black border.

However, the min sdk my app will support is level 10/2.3 and when I run the app in the emulator the whole background of the LinearLayout is black. It seems like 
it is treating the stroke as a fill.

Has anyone come across this?

Edit: I gave the black_border a stroke of white, this somewhat solved my problem. TextViews inside the LinearLayout had no visible border with this change, so a subsequent step was needed to give them a border.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with api level 9.
You have to explicity tell that the solid is transparent.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

    <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/trasparent" android:width="2dp" android:height="2dp"/>

    <size
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

where colorPrimaryDark is defined as black (#FF000000) and transparent is #00000000

I suggest you to use dp for dimensions instead of px.

Comment: I used the same solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got round this by giving black_border a stroke of white. Subsequently I needed to give any TextViews inside the LinearLayout a border as having a white background made them borderless.